# using JSP taglibs in Grails 2.4.0

Tags: grails, jsp-tags

In my Grails 2.3.8 app I'm using the Janrain plugin which includes a JSP taglib. At the top of my layout GSP I declare

```
<%@ taglib prefix="janrain" uri="http://janrain4j.googlecode.com/tags" %>
```

Then I could use this taglib in the same GSP with:

```
<janrain:signInLink styleClass="btn">Login Socially</janrain:signInLink>
```

But after upgrading to Grails 2.4.0 I now get this error

```
Unknown JSP tag janrain:signInLink. Stacktrace follows:
org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.pages.exceptions.GroovyPagesException: Error applying layout : responsive
    at grails.plugin.cache.web.filter.PageFragmentCachingFilter.doFilter(PageFragmentCachingFilter.java:198)
    at grails.plugin.cache.web.filter.AbstractFilter.doFilter(AbstractFilter.java:63)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This information was missing from Grails 2.4 [upgrade notes](http://grails.org/doc/2.4.x/guide/upgradingFrom23.html). I've now added that: https://github.com/grails/grails-doc/commit/871eec21 , [docs on build server](https://hudson.grails.org/job/grails_docs_2.4.x/ws/build/docs/guide/upgradingFrom23.html).

JSP taglib tld files aren't scanned by default any more. This must be configured with the grails.gsp.tldScanPattern setting. It accepts a comma separated String value. Spring's PathMatchingResourcePatternResolver is used to resolve the patterns.

You can get the previous behaviour by adding this setting to Config.groovy:

```
grails.gsp.tldScanPattern='classpath*:/META-INF/*.tld,/WEB-INF/tld/*.tld'
```

JSTL standard library is no more added as a dependency. In case you are using JSTL, you should also add these dependencies:

```
   runtime 'javax.servlet:jstl:1.1.2'
   runtime 'taglibs:standard:1.1.2'
```

Comment: The c.tld file included by default in a grails app has the description that it belongs to the "JSTL 1.2 core library". Shouldn't the JSTL 1.2 libraries be included instead of 1.1.2?

Comment: I am getting an error after I added the first line to Config and the two runtime dependencies in the BuildConfig Error |
Resolve error obtaining dependencies: The following artifacts could not be resolved: javax.servlet:jstl:zip:1.1.2, taglibs:standard:zip:1.1.2: Could not find artifact

Comment: @Viriato, if that happens, you have added the dependencies to the 'plugins {' section of BuildConfig. They should be added to 'dependencies {'.